# Reading number of node from text file in graph

Tags: java, graph, nodes, filereader, vertices

I want to read how many nodes in a text file where it only consists of edges. I do not want to add in the top of my text file to read the number of vertices. Here's what contains in the text file.

```
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5
```

The problem is I cannot get the number of nodes from reading a file. I was thinking if finding the maximum value of nodes and add 1 if it starts with 0. But still I couldn't get it so I tried by reading the nextInt and compare with another nextInt. Here's what I have mean and what is done so far.

```
public static int readNode(String mazeFile) {
    int numNode = 0;
    File mf = new File(mazeFile);
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(mf);
        int arc = readLineCount(mf);
        for (int i = 0; i < arc; i++) {
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                int n1 = scan.nextInt();
                int n2 = scan.nextInt();
                if (n1 > n2) {
                    n2 = n1;
                    numNode = n2;
                } else if (n1 < n2) {
                    n1 = n2;
                    numNode = n1;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numNode;
}
```

Do I need to change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this method you're still counting on the user to give the graph with consecutive integer node numbers. What if someone picks a node number of 1111111111 when there are only 42 nodes in the graph? To fix this, think of node numbers as symbols.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

class Graph {
  final Set<Integer> nodes = new HashSet<>();
  final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> edges = new HashMap<>();

  static class Reader {
    String fileName;
    Graph graph;

    Reader(String fileName) {
      this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    Graph read() {
      try {
        return scanGraph();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ignore) {
        return new Graph();
      }
    }

    Graph scanGraph() throws FileNotFoundException {
      graph = new Graph();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int n2 = scanner.nextInt();
        graph.nodes.add(n1);
        graph.nodes.add(n2);
        addDirectedEdge(n1, n2);
      }
      return graph;
    }

    void addDirectedEdge(Integer n1, Integer n2) {
      if (graph.edges.containsKey(n1)) {
        graph.edges.get(n1).add(n2);
      } else {
        Set<Integer> to = new HashSet<>();
        to.add(n2);
        graph.edges.put(n1, to);
      }
    }    
  }

  interface Visitor {
    void visit(int node);
  }    

  void visitDepthFirst(int start, Visitor visitor) {
    visitDepthFirst(start, visitor, new HashSet<>());
  }

  void visitDepthFirst(int node, Visitor visitor, Set<Integer> visited) {
    visitor.visit(node);
    visited.add(node);
    Set<Integer> successors = edges.get(node);
    if (successors == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (int successor : successors) {
      if (!visited.contains(successor)) {
        visitDepthFirst(successor, visitor, visited);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Graph graph = new Graph.Reader(args[0]).read();
    System.out.println("The graph has " + graph.nodes.size() + " nodes:");
    System.out.println(graph.nodes);
    System.out.println("Adjacency list:");
    System.out.println(graph.edges);
    System.out.println("A preorder depth first visit starting from 0:");
    graph.visitDepthFirst(0, new Visitor() {
      @Override
      public void visit(int node) {
        System.out.println("Visiting " + node);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've fixed some other questionable practice in your code as well. But I haven't used Java 8 functional features, which would make this less verbose.

The output:

```
The graph has 12 nodes:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
Adjacency list:
{0=[3, 5], 1=[4], 2=[3], 5=[4, 7], 6=[7], 7=[8], 8=[9], 9=[10], 11=[3]}
A preorder depth first visit starting from 0:
Visiting 0
Visiting 3
Visiting 5
Visiting 4
Visiting 7
Visiting 8
Visiting 9
Visiting 10
```

NB for brevity I've omitted the niceties of production Java like  public/private and getters/setters.

Comment: @MCMadMoefat Okay it's running now.

Comment: Thank you so much as you gave me the code for idea. Now it works because of that.